# OPENAPI: Could a request contain parameters that are not present in YAML?

Tags: openapi, google-cloud-endpoints

I use Google Endpoint ESPv2 and define my request structure in YAML.
When I send to Endpoint a request that contains fields that are not defined in the YAML I don't receive any errors.
Does it correspond to OPENAPI standard?